# Replacing "imagecopyresized" function with "imagecopyresampled" in image upload module

Tags: php-gd, pligg

I'm currently working on Pligg CMS-based website and its default Image Upload Module which attaches thumbnails to posts from user provided links is using PHP's GD library for image processing. The thumbnails resulted have a reduced quality and after a little bit of web search I found that I should replace the `imagecopyresized` function with `imagecopyresampled`.

The main problem is I am a rookie in web development and I don't know where to start. The chunk of code *I think* (thus maybe wrong) is responsible for the image processing and needs to be edited is the following:

```
// create a new temporary image
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

// copy and resize old image into new image 
while (file_exists("$thumb_dir/$name$i.jpg")) $i++;
$name = "$name$i.jpg";

imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

if (!imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "$thumb_dir/$name",$settings['quality'] ))
    $error .= "Can't create thumbnail $thumb_dir/$name";
else
    $db->query("INSERT INTO ".table_prefix."files 
            SET file_size='$size',
                file_orig_id='$orig_id',
                file_user_id={$current_user->user_id},
                file_link_id=$link_id,
                file_ispicture=1,
                file_comment_id='".$db->escape($_POST['comment'])."',
                file_real_size='".filesize("$thumb_dir/$name")."',
                file_name='".$db->escape($name)."'");
}
return $error;
```

From what I see, the image is first processed through the `imagecreatruecolor` function into a new `tmp_img` which is then processed through the `imagecopyresized` function.

Since I don't have experience, I can't tell if this is the right path for an image of XY size to be resized without reducing its quality. Should I replace both `imagecreatetruecolor` and `imagecopyresized` with `imagecopyresampled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) and [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) have identical parameter requirements so you can simply change the function name in the following line:

```
imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
```

Everything else should stay the same.

Note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Read up on, and start using, [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3775731).